# Getting all var from a javastring function by Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I am new for Regex and trying to get below,
there is a string below in javascript,

```
"function(){var a; var a,b,c;}"
```

and I am trying to find [a,b,c] from it.
Please suggest me to get all variable declared in string, what will be regex.

Comment: OP, can you add the code you've attempted so far, please?

Comment: Yes, something this is like var match=willBeRegex.exec("function(){var a; var a,b,c;}") and match[] has collection of all variable as [a,b,c]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very very manipulative solution, but will serve your purpose

```
function uniq(value,index,self){
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

var str = "function(){var a; var a,b,c;}";
var ptrn = /var [^;]+/g;
var match;
var matches = []
while ( ( match = ptrn.exec(str) ) != null )
{
    matches.push(match.join().split(" ")[1]);
}
console.log(matches.join(",").split(",").filter(uniq));
```

but if you understand this code you wont have to ever search for:

- how to get unique values from js array
- how matching a pattern with exec only returns the first match and we have to loop to get the rest of the values
- finally adding a filter with a function.